# Progressbar в endlessList

Tags: android, progress-bar

Есть бесконечный список, в котором подгружаю n-oe количество элементов после того как пролистал до самого низа. Необходимо во время этой подгрузки отображать `progressBar` в самом низу. Раньше использовал `footerView`, состоящего из `progressBar`, просто скрывал и отображал его когда было необходимо. Но теперь я использую не `listView`, а `recyclerView`, в который, увы, нельзя стандартными способами вставить `header` или `footer`.. Погуглив, нашел пару библиотек, которые используют свой кастомный адаптер, вместо  `RecyclerView.Adapter`. Так не хочется перелопачивать всё в проекте и прикручивать эту "эболу". Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RecyclerView стал очень удобным в кастомизации, это как Lada, большое поле для фантазий, после выхода с конвейера =)

Я недавно также у себя задавался вопросом, как сделать бесконечный список, в итоге сделал так

С начала переопределил метод

```
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return isFooter(position) ? TYPE_FOOTER : TYPE_ITEM;
    }
```

где константы:

```
public static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
public static final int TYPE_FOOTER = 1;

public boolean isFooter(int position) {
        return mIsFooterEnabled && getItemCount() == position + (mIsFooterEnabled ? 1 : 0);
    }
```

так как футер не входит в общий массив то дополним метод

```
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mCatalogData != null ? mCatalogData.size() + (mIsFooterEnabled ? 1 : 0) : 0;
    }
```

футер включаем или выключаем в случае если адаптер реюзаем ну или конец списка.

```
private boolean mIsFooterEnabled;
public void setFooterEnabled(boolean isFooterEnabled) {
        mIsFooterEnabled = isFooterEnabled;

    }
```

Вот так выглядят Холдеры

```
    public static class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    public static class FooterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        FooterViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

        }
    }
```

И соответственно метод `onBindViewHolder`

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int i) {
        if (holder instanceof ProductViewHolder) {
            ProductViewHolder productViewHolder = (ProductViewHolder) holder;

        } else {

        }
    }
```

ну а в этом методе ставим нужные вью.

```
  @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int type) {
        if (type == TYPE_ITEM) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.catalog_list_item, viewGroup, false);
            return new ProductViewHolder(v);
        } else {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.catalog_list_footer, viewGroup, false);
            return new FooterViewHolder(v);
        }
    }
```

что написано в `catalog_list_item` кидать не буду, излишне, а в `catalog_list_footer` просто прогресс бар.

**UPD** Подгрузку начинаю делать, когда покажется вью на экране с позицией getItemCount()-10.

```
mGridView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                int position = ((GridLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                int updatePosition = recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 10;
                if (position >= updatePosition) {

                        loadNewItems();


                }
            }
        });
```

а данные вставляю вот так (Метод внутри адпатера)

```
public void setData(List<ProductData> data) {
        if (mCatalogData == null) {
            mCatalogData = new ArrayList<>();

        }
        mCatalogData.addAll(data);
        notifyItemInserted(getItemCount() - data.size());
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо! Да, я видео подобное решение. А в самом фрагменте Вы изменяли код для addOnScrollListener? или оставляли как обычно?

Comment: Добавил в ответ еще 2 фрагмента, да без addOnScrollListener подгрузку не сделать. Прогресс бар Висит всегда, но вы его можете скрыть, если к примеру будет ошибка сети.

Comment: Ага, понял. Решение выглядит более правильным чем моё=) Помечу как ответ

Comment: Но если список разделен на два (например, два CardView бок о бок), тогда спиннер (ProgressBar) будет показываться сбоку. Не комильфо.

Comment: @Trancer данный пример описан для LinearLayoutManager, То что вы хотите это для GridLayoutManager, в таком случае вам нужно динамически менять span

Comment: @Chaynik GridLayoutManager - это GridLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager. А разве, если динамически изменить span, весь список не поменяется на простой одно-колоночный вместо 2-х?

Comment: @Trancer ,нет если это делать вот так - https://stackoverflow.com/a/30809425

Answer (score 1):

Если кому интересно будет, то я сделал таким образом:

1) В разметку с `RecyclerView` добавил `progressBar`

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/eventsRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@xml/progressbar_background"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

2) Далее во фрагменте, к `recyclerView`  вешаю слушатель `onScrollListener` в котором смотрю, когда необходимо грузить элементы, то показываю свой `progressBar`

```
if (loading) {
   if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
          pageNumber++;
          progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          loadList();
          loading = false;
      }
}
```

3) В своём методе `loadList()` , после загрузки элементов и обновлении адаптера, присваиваю значение `loading = true` и `progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE).`

Единственное что остается сделать, это плавное появление `progressBara` снизу.