# Progress bar в бесконечном ListView

Tags: android

как реализовать progress bar во время подгрузки данных в ListView?

Comment: Задавался таким вопросом ранее. Вот тут решение http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/508475/progressbar-%D0%B2-endlesslist

Comment: посмотрите тут https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первую очередь в xml разметке добавить компонент progress bar:

```js
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:indeterminate="true"/>
```

значение gone параметра visibility, делает компонент невидимым.

Далее в коде, перед началом загрузки данных в ListView, делаете видимым ProgressBar:

```js
mPbData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

После завершения загрузки данных ProgressBar нужно сделать снова невидимым:

```js
mPbData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```